# Don't want to show LINK used on IFRAME KML the my site

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, iframe

display kml link google in tag a ,
but ,
not display kml link google in iframe ,
The unsuccessful am display in iframe

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zmLLyZ0RAAIY.kpwcoomkTAXw&usp=sharing">link</a>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zmLLyZ0RAAIY.kpwcoomkTAXw&usp=sharing"></iframe>
```

Comment: maybe some more details? Those two lines of code don't help us understand what you're asking

Comment: display kml link google in tag a , but , not display kml link google in iframe , The unsuccessful am display in iframe

Comment: The Iframe content is subject to the same-domain policy. If it's from your domain, you can control it, if not, you're locked out. This prevents all kinds of Iframe-based page hijacking. Since the link in the question is from google maps, I guess it's not from your domain. So, you're stuck with the link inside the iframe unless you do some preprocessing on the server side.

Comment: The processing on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zmLLyZ0RAAIY.kpwcoomkTAXw&usp=sharing"></iframe>
```